# Open a php page in a modal box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating an images feed but there is also content with images. When is image clicked, page single-image.php is called.

I am trying to open single-image.php in a modal box, but it isn't working

single-image.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <section id="content" role="main" class="ip-main">
      <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

       <?php
       /* BEGIN IMAGEPRESS CODE */
       /* main image display (required) */
            if(function_exists('ip_main'))
                ip_main(get_the_ID());

       /* related images (optional, can be placed in the sidebar) */
            if(function_exists('ip_related'))
                ip_related(get_the_ID());
            /* END IMAGEPRESS CODE */
            ?>
        </article>


        <?php comments_template('', true); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, that isn't much help. Do you have a HTML with a Modal box plugin setup? Where's the link to open the modal window, we need more information.

Comment: php does not working. first: server execute u php. second: if u php creating html -  server give this html code to u browser.

Comment: So, I am calling a shortcode on a page that displays grid of images. Once a single image is clicked it calls this page single-image.php above and open a new page Mysite.com/image/<title of image>                                                          Instead of opening this page, I want it to appear in a lightbox/modal box